# Distribution of a sum of a product of Bernoulli vectors divided by the sum of the first Bernoulli vector

Tags: bernoulli-distribution, poisson-binomial-distribution

I'm trying to understand the distribution of a normalized sum of a product of Bernoulli random variables. Specifically, I have two vectors $M_1$ and $M_2$ of length n. Each element of each vector is a Bernoulli random variable with varying success probability $p_i$. We can assume for now that each element is independent from all other elements and the vectors are independent from each other. With this assumption the sum of elements of vector $M_1$ is $\sum_i M_{1i}$ and follows a Poisson binomial distribution with expected value $\sum_i p_{1i}$. The element-wise product of both vectors $M_1 M_2$ consists again of Bernoulli random variables, this time with success probabilities $p_{1i}p_{2i}$ for each element. The sum of this vector of products $\sum_i M_{1i}M_{2i}$ (which is also the inner product of the two vectors) is then again distributed with a Poisson binomial distribution with expected value $\sum_i p_{1i}p_{2i}$.
What I am interested in now is the distribution of $Z=\frac{\sum_i M_{1i}M_{2i}}{\sum_i M_{1i}}$. Basically this is the number of common successes between the two vectors divided by the number of successes in the first vector. This problem seems simple enough to possibly have a closed-form expression, but I don't know what to look for. Assumptions of n being large are acceptable, but exact solutions are preferred. Any pointers to either a solution or a problem of a similar form in an application would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If by "closed-form" you mean an expression that asymptotically in $n$ is $o(n)$ in length, you will necessarily be disappointed because it depends (at a minimum) on all the $p_{2i}$ separately. Approximations can be developed by making assumptions about the average relationships among the $p_{i1}$ and $p_{2i},$ so if you have such information, please share it.

Comment: thank you for the clarification. I'm fine if the expression depends on all the p_{2i}, especially if like in the Poisson Binomial Distribution it would result in a straightforward expected value and variance. Even better of course would be if it converges to a well-known distribution. On the average relationship between p_{1i} and p_{2i} : I don't think there is anything else but to say that they are conditionally independent from each other. But would specifying P(p_{2i}|p_{1i}) be helpful? I might be able to make an assumption based on what my data shows

Comment: Convergence results likely depend on details of what happens to the $p_{ji}$ as $i$ grows large.

Comment: p_{ji} would not change in distribution as i gets large, in the sense of probabilities becoming smaller or larger, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Are you supposing these values are themselves random variables?  If so, that would be useful information to include -- along with any assumptions about those distributions.

Comment: The p_{ji} are themselves derived from another random variable, and are basically portraying the chance that that random variable crosses a certain threshold (in this case 1). Sadly, I can't make a good assumption about the distribution of those underlying random variables. Not a priori, and in the data they look all over the place as well. But one could consider the p_{ji} as a random variable. Could you briefly sketch why that would help?

Comment: It could help by providing a simple, parsimonious asymptotic characterization of the $p_{ji}$ in terms of parameters of a family of possible distributions.  That's a huge improvement over assuming nothing at all about them and creates the possibility of a closed-form approximate solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt at the distribution; more elegant/compact solutions quite possibly exist however.

Let $A:=\sum_i M_{1i}$ and $B:=\sum_i M_{1i}M_{2i}$. Also, suppose for some given $A$, let $M_1^{A,k}$ correspond to a specific $M_1$ vector whose sum is $A$. So, there are ${n\choose A}$ different $M_1^{A,k}$ vectors for a given value of $A$.

The joint PMF $P(A=a,B=b)$ where $b\leq a\leq n$ is
\begin{align*}
P(A,B) &= P(A)P(B|A)\\
&= P(A)\sum_kP(B|M_1^{A,k})P(M_1^{A,k}|A)\\
&= \sum_kP(B|M_1^{A,k})P(M_1^{A,k})
\end{align*}
Now, $P(B|M_1^{A,k})$ is a Poisson-binominal PMF. Specifically, suppose $\{j\}$ is the set of indices of the "successful" components of $M_1^{A,k}$. We then look at $M_2$ and focus on its $j$ components as well; $P(B|M_1^{A,k})$ is simply the probability that $B$ of those $M_{2j}$ components are successful.

Now, we look at $P(M_1^{A,k})$, which is simply the probability of having the $j$ components be the successful ones, ie $P(M_1^{A,k})=\prod_{i\in\{j\}}p_{1i}\cdot \prod_{i\not\in\{j\}}(1-p_{1i})$

Now that we have expressions for our summands in the joint PMF $P(A,B)$, we turn to $Z=\frac{B}{A}$. Clearly $Z$ is discrete and rational-valued. Its PMF will be
$$P(Z=z)=\sum_{(a,b)\;st.\;b/a=z,\; b\leq a\leq n }P(A=a,B=b)$$

Technically that's it, and it's "closed-form" given all the sums/products are finite. But it's ugly sorry!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is really helpful with notation and with the conditional probability idea, will +1 once I have enough reputation. I won't accept it yet hoping that someone will come up with a smart assumption that can lead to a nice closed-form solution or at least approximation. Could you think of a similar problem to this which does have a known distribution as the solution? Maybe I could take some inspiration from there

Comment: @NilsR I imagine things will simply greatly if further assumptions or restrictions are placed on the $p_{ji}$ values; otherwise, I fail to see how we can avoid long sums or products. The other thing of course is that $Z$ is rational, so its PMF will likely exihibit lots of "unsmoothness", which is not conducive to the existence of a compact PMF (which is likely to be continuous if extended to the reals).